# Php preg_replace() using

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace

I'm trying to change some parts of a string. I used preg_replace() function for this stuation but I couldn't succeed.

Here is an example.

```
$str = "Suspendisse rutrum rhoncus leo vitae vehicula. <span class="sdsad"> Nunc nec dapibus nisi.</span> Donec facilisis mauris sapien, eget blandit enim  dignissim auctor. <span style="text-decoration: underline;" class="sadsad">Nullam a porta orci.</span>";
```

I need to get parts begin with `"<span"` and after all till `">"` charecter and turn it `<p>` or something else.

```
$str = preg_replace('/<span.*>/', '<p>', $str);
```

I'm trying to solve this like that but it returns the same value.

What do I need to do this ?

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

This Regex will do the trick for you.

```
$str = 'Suspendisse rutrum rhoncus leo </span> vitae vehicula. <span class="sdsad"> Nunc nec dapibus nisi.</span> Donec facilisis mauris sapien, eget blandit enim  dignissim auctor. <span style="text-decoration: underline;" class="sadsad">Nullam a porta orci.</span>';
$str_replaced = preg_replace('/<(\/{0,1})span[^>]*>/','<$1p>',$str);
echo $str_replaced;
```

It will optionally put the trailing slash into the tags so you will only need one call.

Comment: Way to complicated ?!

Comment: Not at all. This way you will have <span clas="xyz"> and </span> replaced with <p> and </p> in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the capturing group here `()`

```
$str = preg_replace('/<span(.*)>/', '<p>', $str);
```

More info here:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: unfortunately I'm getting the same result.

Comment: @brk: I tested this on http://infoheap.com/tool/php-preg_replace-sandbox/ - works perfectly. Maybe some kind of cache?

Comment: yes it's working correctly in that link. i'm trying tıo find some reasons.